# What facilities does Ottawa airport provide after security?

Tags: air-travel, ottawa, yow

Is there a pharmacy and a sit-down restaurant available after security at Ottawa airport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The airport has a very good homepage where you can get a list of restaurants, filtered by areas:

https://yow.ca/en/eat-drink-and-shop/restaurants

The same applies for shops:

https://yow.ca/en/eat-drink-and-shop/shops

It depends whether you fly to Canada/USA/any other country, but there are sit down restaurants available, but no pharmacy, even pre security. It could be that other shops sell the most important pharmacy products though.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check out [this link](http://www.ifly.com/ottawa-international-airport/shops-stores)

To sum up what is on that page: Senate Chambers Bar, Harveys, Grab & Go, DArcy McGees, Byward Taps, Booster Juice and Bytown Marche.